# Mysql - how to retrieve data from a database(mysql) and print it.(php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database IN MYSQL from where I wish to retrieve data and print it, how do I do it?
The columns in it are title and blogs. I wish to print the title content as the heading and the blog content in a paragraph.

Comment: Have you tried anything for this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the data , use "select"

```
select title,blogs from table name
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Use following links

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Here.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","databasename");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT blogs, title FROM tableName");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";
  echo "<p>".$row['blogs']."</p>";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```